# What is the best way to associate a JWT token with an existing internal user account?

Tags: jwt, authorization, mapping

I have an web application that has been working for many years and the internal user accounts are all in a database table.  Tons of code has been written around the internal user as far as authorization.

Recently, however, a requirement is to allow users to use their own user account via Amazon, Google or some other identity provider.  So they will no longer use the internal user account.

Instead of writing all new code around the new identities, the JWT token I get back from the identity provider needs to be mapped (associated) with the internal user account, so the code continues to function as it was.

My question is, is there any good way to map JWT to an internal user account?  Should I store the JWT in the database on the appropriate user record? Should I store only the "sub" property of the payload on the user account record?